# AWS Lambda no se está ejecutando al subir un tag de git a traves de CodeCommit

Tags: git, aws, lambda

estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un proceso de CI/CD implementado con los siguientes servicios en AWS:

- Alguien pushea un cambio a un repositorio de CodeCommit
- Se ejecuta una función Lambda como trigger
- Se inicia un proceso en CodeBuild

El proceso se dispara correctamente cuando se pushea un cambio a cualquiera de las ramas (develop o master) pero no está funcionando cuando se pushea un tag. Es decir:

`git push origin develop` sobre CodeCommit -> La funcion Lambda se ejecuta correctamente e inicia el proceso de CodeBuild

`git push origin master` sobre CodeCommit -> La funcion Lambda se ejecuta correctamente e inicia el proceso de CodeBuild

`git tag 1.0.0`
`git push --tags` sobre CodeCommit -> La funcion Lambda NO se ejecuta.

Tengo configurada la funcion Lambda con los siguientes parametros:

```
Branches: develop, master
Custom data: my-codebuild-project
Events: createReference, updateReference
Repository name: my-codecommit-repo
Service principal: codecommit.amazonaws.com
Statement ID: lambda-5b3c4bd9-921d-4ee7-9177-a7b1a1f8132c
Trigger name: my-lambda-trigger
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Cuando indicas `Branches: tal, cual`, significa que solo va a reaccionar si hay pushes a esas ramas? Si la respuesta es _"si"_ entonces debe haber otro setting para que se dispare para tags.... Me equivoco?

Comment: De la documentacion oficial de AWS:

Puede crear disparadores para eventos que especifique, como por ejemplo cuando se inserta una confirmación en un repositorio. Entre los tipos de eventos se incluyen:

__all: todos los eventos del repositorio y las ramificaciones especificados.__

__updateReference: si las confirmaciones se envían al repositorio y ramificaciones especificados.__

__createReference: si se crea una nueva ramificación o etiqueta en el repositorio especificado.__

En teoría createReference y updateReference deberia funcionar para tags ademas de branches.

Comment: Suena a que asumes que los campos de `Branches` y `Events` se complementan..... Puede que sea el caso.... Pero podría ser que se apliquen en un `and`.... Haz algunas pruebas para verificar cuál es el caso.... Por ejemplo, configúralo con `Todos los branches` y prueba a empujar una etiqueta.... Si funciona, ya sabes por dónde van los tiros

Comment: @eftshift0 exactamente era eso! Tuve que configurarlo con “Todos los branches” y ahí recién se dispara la función al pushear un tag

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo resolví configurando la opción “Branches” para “Todos los Branches” en lugar de “Master” y “Develop” por separado. Por alguna razón Lambda no se ejecuta al pushear un tag si esa opción no esta configurada de esa manera.